# Ruby on rails : form select option with issue in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I want to show a list of existing chapters in database in my form. So, I used scaffold to generate my models and I have a form like this :

```
  [...]
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :chapter_id %>
    <%= f.number_field :chapter_id %>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <%= f.submit "Create scene", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

The admin should choose between the existing `chapter_id`, however there is an error. For ease, I thought about a way to present to the user the list of existing chapters only. It will be easier to click on, it will limit errors. I tried something with `<select>` but it doesn't work at all.

I hope you understand my problem, and sorry for my bad English.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `f.select`.

So it's going to be something like:

```
<%= f.select :chapter_id, @chapters.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }  %>
```

In your controller:

```
@chapters = Chapter.all
```